# Java Regex Understanding

Tags: java, regex

I need help to understand regex. For some reason, i'v read lots of tutorials and lots of questions here on sof, and cannot manage to understand it. I want to use `String.split` function like in here: [Java string.split - by multiple character delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492672/java-string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter). But i cant understand this part:

```
String[] parts = input.split("[,\\s\\-:\\?]");
```

Lets supose i want to make a split with this following delimiters: " " (space), "." (full stop), "," (coma), "!", "»", "«", etc. How can i get this with regex? I want understand what this characters in here: ("[,\s\-:\?]") are. What does "\s", why is it needed.

Comment: I recommend this website for testing your regular expressions: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It also offers explanations for the pattern itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s` is "any single whitespace character". So it represents a space, newline, tab, or other such.

Note that the regex could actually be written more compactly in this case:

```
String[] parts = input.split("[,\\s:?-]");
```

(`?` doesn't need to be escaped when inside `[]`, and `-` doesn't either if it's the last thing.)

For more details about character classes, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html