# How to split string in java when there are multiple criteria to split

Tags: java, string

To split a paragraph into an array of individual words (say a string array), the most common answer would be something like:

```
String para = "ameya needs to win this cup.";
String[] abc = para.split(" ");
```

However if the para included ? and ,'s and ; etc, how can this be done?
For eg:

```
String para = "ameya,needs. to win?this cup.";
```

Comment: you are probably gonna want to use regex

Comment: OK, let's say this is an interview question... first what is **your** answer??

Comment: Don't get why a little googling cant help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492672/java-string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter

Answer (score 1):

`String#split(arg)` takes regex as argument, and in regex if you want to match one of many characters then you can use this form `(a|b|c|...|z)` which means character that is eater `a OR b OR c OR [...] OR z` (instead of `...` you actually need to put rest of alphabet letters).

But since that form is ugly you can use [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that can look like `[abcd...z]`. But this can also be optimized a little using range of characters `[a-z]`.

Now lets go back to your question. If you want to match all spaces and additional characters then you can try to split on every `[\\s.,;?]`. Also in case you want to split on single group of that characters you can use `[\\s.,;?]+`. `+` means one or more elements that are described before `+`.

So maybe try this way

```
String[] abc = para.split("[\\s.,;?]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression

```
String str = "ameya,needs. to win?this cup.";
String [] arr = str.split("[\\s|,|\\.|;|\\?]");
```

Comment: Same: this is a character class

Comment: What fge meant to say is that you don't need to use `|` inside `[...]` to say OR. Right now you are including `|` into your character class so it will also match every `|` in data string.