# Splitting a string in java on more than one symbol

Tags: java, string, symbols, split

I want to split a string when following of the symbols encounter "+,-,*,/,="
I am using split function but this function can take only one argument.Moreover it is not working on "+".
I am using following code:-

```
Stringname.split("Symbol");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you started by reading the javadoc? There must be some explanation as to why splitting on `+` doesn't give you what you want.

Comment: Maybe have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492672/java-string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`String.split` takes a regular expression as argument.

This means you can alternate whatever symbol or text abstraction in one parameter in order to split your `String`.

See documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Here's an example in your case:

```
String toSplit = "a+b-c*d/e=f";
String[] splitted = toSplit.split("[-+*/=]");
for (String split: splitted) {
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Notes:

- Reserved characters for `Pattern`s must be double-escaped with `\\`. **Edit**: Not needed here.
- The `[]` brackets in the pattern indicate a character class.
- More on `Pattern`s [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @RohitJain yep, just realized. I've edited my answer, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @saumyaraj I don't understand your question?

Comment: I mean that when i use "+" in split function it showed me error something like "Dangling meta character". Can u explain a bit about this error?Thanks

Comment: @saumyaraj yes. That is a meta-character, as in, a reserved character for a `Pattern`. It indicates a quantifier (see the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) page for more info). It'll work ok in a character class, but will need to be escaped if interpreted as literal "+" outside a character class. In your case, just try double escaping it as `\\+` instead of `+`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a regular expression:

```
String[] tokens = input.split("[+*/=-]");
```

Note: `-` should be placed in first or last position to make sure it is not considered as a range separator.

Comment: `input.split("[+*-/=]");` also includes `,` and `.`. Just split `"a,b.c"` as an example, because the range from `*` to `/` includes those characters.

Comment: `input.split("[+*/-=]");` even includes digits, the colon, semicolon and the `<` symbol.

Comment: The dash inside a character class is always considered a range seperator, except if it's in the first or last position.

Answer (score 6):

You need Regular Expression. Addionaly you need the regex `OR` operator:

```
String[]tokens = Stringname.split("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\=");
```

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need to use an appropriate regex statement. Most of the symbols you listed are reserved in regex, so you'll have to escape them with `\`.

A very baseline expression would be `\+|\-|\\|\*|\=`. Relatively easy to understand, each symbol you want is escaped with `\`, and each symbol is separated by the `|` (or) symbol. If, for example, you wanted to add `^` as well, all you would need to do is append `|\^` to that statement.

For testing and quick expressions, I like to use www.regexpal.com