# Java , how can i split this sentence into array?

Tags: java, split

How can i split a sentence what is plotted with space and , in same time

E.g

```
String Sentence="Please , tell me about : job, hobby";
```

`String[] words = Sentence.split(" ");`<--- so here i need `','  ':' ' '` splits,
How can i resolve multiple splitting?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492672/java-string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a non-word command and a quantifier:

```
String sentence="Please , tell me about : job, hobby";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sentence.split("\\W+")));
```

**Output**

```
[Please, tell, me, about, job, hobby]
```

You can also use a character class with the specific tokens you need:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sentence.split("[,: ]+")));
```

(same output)

**Docs**

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).